# PHP approach to python's magic __getattr__()

Tags: php, python, getattr

I was wondering if there was some way in PHP to duplicate some of the magic of Python attribute/key access.

I use a Mongo ORM class written by [Steve Lacey](https://github.com/slacy) called [Minimongo](https://github.com/slacy/minimongo) in which he utilizes the `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` to reroute key and attribute flavored access and preserve the 'document-oriented' nature of Mongo.  `val = doc.foo` and `val = doc['foo']` become equivalent.

I was wondering if there is a similar interface in PHP that would allow the changing of how object access is handled for a class that inherits  from it.  I looked through the STL and couldn't find one that filled suit.  It would be greatly useful for setting up defaults.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the nice question, simple in itself, but requiring elegance :-) See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [__get() and __set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

With the former you can make non-public members accessbile, as in `$obj->foo`, with the latter you can access them like `$obj['foo']`.

You can hardwire them however you like, internally.

Personally I would suggest you keep these magically-accessible properties into one single array member of the class, so you don't end up with spaghetti code.

POC:

```
 1  <?php
 2  class Magic implements ArrayAccess {
 3  
 4      protected $items = array();
 5  
 6      public function offsetExists($key) {
 7          return isset($this->items[$key]);
 8      }
 9      public function offsetGet($key) {
10          return $this->items[$key];
11      }
12      public function offsetSet($key, $value) {
13          $this->items[$key] = $value;
14      }
15      public function offsetUnset($key) {
16          unset($this->items[$key]);
17      }
18  
19      //do not modify below, this makes sure we have a consistent
20      //implementation only by using ArrayAccess-specific methods
21      public function __get($key) {
22          return $this->offsetGet($key);
23      }
24      public function __set($key, $value) {
25          $this->offsetSet($key, $value);
26      }
27      public function __isset($key) {
28          return $this->offsetExists($key);
29      }
30      public function __unset($key) {
31          $this->offsetUnset($key);
32      }
33  }
34  
35  //demonstrate the rountrip of magic
36  $foo = new Magic;
37  $foo['bar'] = 42;
38  echo $foo->bar, PHP_EOL;//output 42
39  $foo->bar++;
40  echo $foo['bar'];//output 43
41
```

Consistency Milord, exactly as you asked.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Basically what I was looking to do was make a class that could take a stdClass from a call to json_decode and allow this kind of access but return false by default if a key didnt exist.  Schemaless data definitely requires this.   It really lifts a burden that have this failsafe in my PHP now... I love it in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Magic Methods of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

`__get()`, `__set()` and `__call()` could do what you want.